# MIKTeX reinstallation failed

Tags: miktex2.9

I made a big mistake, which I would now like to correct. I uninstalled MikTex and then reinstalled it to update it. Yeah, I know it's stupid, but I did it. 
After installing MikTex2.9, Texstudio and Texworks don't find the most basic packages anymore. This already starts with the KOMA script...
I have already tried to install MikTex in a new folder. But that doesn't help.
What can I do?

Thank you for your help!
Arne

Comment: Try the portable version of MikTeX. Then Windows doesn't go looking for the files; you launch a MikTeX control panel, which operates everything from within it.

Comment: Did you reinstall koma-script? (it is not part of the basic installation).

Comment: Make sure that all remnants of the old installation are removed. If you only installed the basic installation, then you need to install  quite a few packages before you can use them. Not all packages are included in the basic installation.

Comment: Stop doing anything like deinstalling and reinstalling. Make a survey what works and what not. Does a hello-world file which uses the class article compile? Did you check in the console which packages are installed? Can you install more?

Comment: I'm using `chocolatey` to manage upgrade of my software. You can use it too to automate updates. `choco install miktex` then form time to time do in command line PowerShell `choco upgrade all`

Comment: MikTeX has an update tool, but you should check if it is not updating more than you want or need.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that TexStudio is using the proper path. There's an option on Options -> Commands (in advanced options) where you can set the variables in PATH.

Make sure that this matches your MikTex installation folder. Also you can change the individual commands executable too.